# How to open other mobile apps from within a Kotlin Multiplatform app?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, android-intent, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to understand how to open other apps from within a Kotlin Multiplatform app. I am creating a contacts app for iOS and Android and I want to make a button which lets the user call a contact in a 3rd party app (e.g. WhatsApp, Google Meet etc.).

An example interaction:

1. In my app, the user navigates to the contact they want to call.
2. User presses the 'Video call' button.
3. My app opens the Google Meet app and creates a new video call.

I was able to implement this sort of functionality in Android/Java using Android intents:

```java
Intent viewContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

viewContact.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.tachyon",
                        "com.google.android.apps.tachyon.ContactsVideoActionActivity");

viewContact.setData(Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/2173"));
```

This intent opens the Google Meet app and starts a video call with the contact ID:2173.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to open external apps in common code?
- Is there a multiplatform equivalent of Android intents?
- On the other hand, if I have to create separate implementations for Android and iOS, how do I open an external iOS app?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is there a way to open external apps in common code?

  - No, not "out of the box" anyway. Opening apps is a platform-specific thing, so Kotlin stdlib doesn't have a way to do this.
- Is there a multiplatform equivalent of Android intents?

  - Same answer. Intents are Android-specific.
- On the other hand, if I
  have to create separate implementations for Android and iOS, how do I
  open an external iOS app?

  - That's kind of an app-specific question. Facetime? Google meet (if installed)? The good news is, I'm sure there's plenty of "how do I do ___ in Swift?" questions you could reference.

It seems like you'll need to implement both the contact navigation, and passing over to the video client. Both of these are platform-specific. I would suggest having a basic interface defined in common code, then when your app starts, pass in platform-specific implementations.

I gave a talk that covers (some of) this. Mostly from the iOS side. The part where I suggest not using cinterop and just passing in an implementation is the important part.

https://www.droidcon.com/2022/06/28/sdk-design-and-publishing-for-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile/